# Retrieve wchar_t* from C++ to C++/CLI to C#

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I have the following C++ function from the MyCppLib.h file of a third party library:

```
int CppFunc(int Index, wchar_t* String, int StringLength);
```

where the maximum length of String is StringLength. String is returned by the function (out).
I am trying to wrap this in C++/CLI for use in C#. According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/calling-native-functions-from-managed-code?view=msvc-160) it looks like StringBuilder should be used to marshall wchar_t* back to C++/CLI.

So I believe the C++/CLI should look something like this:

```
#include "MyCppLib.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;

namespace MyCppCliLib
{
    int CppCliFunc(int Index, StringBuilder^ sB, int StringLength) {
        return ::CppFunc(Index, ???, StringLength);
    }
}
```

Now, how can I retrieve the wchar_t* from C++ back to StringBuilder^ ? I can't find a good example on the topic...

I believe the C# side would then looks like:

```
StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();

int x = CppCliFunc(2, sB, 4096);
```

### EDITS:

Thanks to all the comments, I finally got something working, it looks like this (don't quote me on it, it's my first steps in C++/CLI):

```
#include "MyCppLib.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;

namespace MyCppCliLib
{
    String^ CppCliFunc(int Index, int StringLength) {

        String^ newString="";
        wchar_t* wchar = (wchar_t*)calloc(StringLength, sizeof(wchar_t));

        if (wchar != NULL) {
            int errorInt = ::CppFunc(Index, wchar, StringLength);
            newString = gcnew String(wchar);
            if(errorInt  != 0){
              throw gcnew Exception("Error #" + errorInt.ToString());
            }
        }else{
            throw gcnew Exception("Error wchar is null");
        }
       
        free(wchar);

        return newString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not have `CppCliFunc()` use a local `StringBuilder` internally, or even just a plain `wchar_t[]` array, when calling `CppFunc()`, and then return a plain `String` to C#?

Comment: Does this function return how much of the buffer it actually used, or how do you know that?

Comment: StringBuilder is appropriate for pinvoke with [DllImport], that's not what you're doing.  Simply declare the wchar_t[] as a local variable.  Throw exceptions when the native function indicates an error return value.  CppCliFunc() must be a member of a class to make it usable from C#.  Making the C++/CLI method declaration look like `String^ CppCliFunc(int index)`

Comment: "declare the wchar_t[] as a local variable" is only a good approach when the maximum length is fixed and small.  Here it's controlled by an argument.  `std::wstring` would be the way to manage the buffer needed by the native function, then `return gcnew System::String(&ws[0], ws.size());`

Comment: You are trying too hard to use the C# marshaling way. With C++/CLI, you can (and should) be using _IJW_ to pass blittable arguments directly. In other words, C++/CLI knows what a `wchar_t` is, and so does C++; and, they both know they are exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks to all the comments, I finally got something working, see EDITS above.